# Identify matched (sub) regular expression when text matched

Tags: java, regex

Is there a possibility to resolve the identified pattern group name when a group was matched in Java?

E.G.: 
Combined pattern: `(?<A_Pattern>A\n)|(?<B_Pattern>B\n)|(?<C_Pattern>C\n)`
Program:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fromFile(logFilename));

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    // should output e.g. A_Pattern
    System.out.println("Found pattern: " + matcher.groupName());
}
```

Background: 
I am developing a program to search in log files for regular expressions. This is not the problem, but I have three big problems:

- huge log file: file should be only passed one time due to better performance
- user should be able to enter several patterns with one name each (to identify the name)
- when pattern matched: output regular expression name

Therefore I concat the patterns (regular expressions) into one expression and try to add the names as group names but I did not found the option in Java to resolve the identified name.

Is there a possibility to do this with regular expression group names or any other solution. Group names are just a try.

Comment: even without group names, not matched capturing groups return null, so that if `(?:(A)|(B))` matches, either index 1 or index 2 will return null

Comment: I had this idea also but unfortunately I do not know how much sub regular expressions are merged. Therefore I can not pass every `matcher->group(index)`. Or do I miss there something?

Comment: Neither [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) nor [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) can tell you what the group names are. You can ask for the values captured for a *known* group name, but *you* have to know the names.

Comment: Ok, thank you - is there any other possibility to identify a sub regex?

Comment: Question: If the file is *huge*, then loading the entire file into memory is not possible, so wouldn't you be reading the file one line at a time?

Comment: I guess the problem is speed. BTW, for speed, don't forget to anchor regexes to the start of the line with `^`

Comment: @WalterTross `^` is not anchored to start-of-line by default. You have to give the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) option or the `(?m)` flag expression.

Comment: By start of the line I meant start of the string, since in this case I suppose each line would be read into a string and matched individually

Comment: @WalterTross Only if OP answers yes to my question. As OP's question is currently written, entire file is loaded (`fromFile()`) and matched in one operation.

Comment: I was inspired by this pie of code: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/37-java-util-regex/1716-how-to-apply-regular-expressions-on-the-contents-of-a-file.html - I read some pages about how to avoid to load the whole file content in memory and this pie of code is pretty similar to their suggestions. So yes, I want to read it line by line or at least step by step. Honestly I did not tested the memory usage, but at the moment the identification of a sub pattern is more important. All the other optimization stuff can be fixed later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your sub-expressions don't contain capturing groups, then you could do this:

```
String regex = "(A\n)|(B\n)|(C\n)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null)
        System.out.println("Found pattern A at index " + matcher.start(1));
    else if (matcher.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println("Found pattern B at index " + matcher.start(2));
    else
        System.out.println("Found pattern C at index " + matcher.start(3));
}
```

---

If you have N patterns to match, patterns are allowed to contain capturing groups, and you need to know which pattern matched, you can assign named groups like this:

```
String[] patterns = { "ABC", "D(EF)", "XYZ" };
String input = "Lorem ipsum DEF dolor sit ABC amet, XYZ consectetur DEF adipiscing elit";

String[] names = new String[patterns.length];
StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
    Pattern.compile(patterns[i]); // validate
    names[i] = "Pattern" + (i+1);
    if (i != 0)
        regex.append('|');
    regex.append("(?<").append(names[i]).append('>').append(patterns[i]).append(')');
}
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());

for (Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); matcher.find(); )
    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++)
        if (matcher.start(names[i]) != -1) {
            System.out.println("Found " + names[i] +
                               " at index " + matcher.start(names[i]) +
                               ": " + matcher.group(names[i]));
            break;
        }
```

Output:

```
Found Pattern2 at index 12: DEF
Found Pattern1 at index 26: ABC
Found Pattern3 at index 36: XYZ
Found Pattern2 at index 52: DEF
```

As you can see, match detection worked fine, even with a capturing group in the second pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately I do not know this. They should be able to have sub capturing groups. Therefore I hoped that I could give the parent groups a name to identify them :-/

Comment: You can if *you* assign the names, because then you'd know the names and can use the same methodology described here, except you'd call `group(name1)` and `start(name1)` instead. Or with multiple names, perhaps they are in an array: `group(name[i])` and `start(name[i])`, looping `i` until a non-null value is found.